# Ambiguity in Theorem 4.3. Apostol's book

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

In Theorem 4.2. of Apostol's Analytic Number Theory Abel's identity is introduced. Theorem 4.3. is an application for the identity and claims the equality $$\theta(x) = \pi(x) \log (x) - \int_{3/2}^x \dfrac{\pi(t)}{t} dt = \pi(x) \log (x) - \int_2^x \dfrac{\pi(t)}{t} dt,$$ which is a result of taking $y=3/2$ in Abel's identity but if we take $y=2$ we will have $$\theta(x) = \pi(x) \log (x) - \pi(2) \log (2) - \int_2^x \dfrac{\pi(t)}{t} dt \ne \pi(x) \log (x) - \int_2^x \dfrac{\pi(t)}{t} dt,$$ since integral of a single point is zero.

How this contradiction is resolved?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, if we take two values 5/2 and 3 again the same problem occurs.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, if 4.3. holds for $x \ge 2$ then it holds for $x \ge 4$ and so on. My question is different and it is that there is an extra nonzero term becasue $\pi(t)$ acts like a step function per se, but not similarly inside the intgral.

Comment: But you said yourself, if $y\ge 2$ is applied, it is simply not true. This extra nonzero term needs to be zero by using $\pi(y)=0$, which is true for $y<2$. And yes, the statement may hold for $x\ge 4$, but not for $y=2$ and $x\ge 2$, because, say, for $x=2$ it violates $0<x<y=2$, the assumption of $4.2$.

Comment: The whole thing is discontinuous, so you will arrive at different results if you take the limit $y\to2$ in different directions.